# How to get information about the end user who uninstalled my application

Tags: android, ios

Is it possible to know get information about the user who uninstalled my application as google console shows only the stats about the total number of uninstalls and  installs,but in my case i want to know who uninstalled my application any suggestions appreciated.

Note : I do have all user email id who installed my application.

Comment: There is no ways to do this

Comment: whats wrong with my question. If you have answers then post whats need of negotiating the question .

Comment: i believe people are downvoting as they feel it's not a good question. But anyhow, it's due to privacy act as well. If every user who uninstalled an app and they get bombarded with emails, it will be a big issue in future to the community

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to know who removed your app.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge it is not possible to track the uninstalled user records from our end.we can get that uninstalled user data only from Google console.

Suggestion : It is better to maintain a active and inactive users list to estimate approximate active users for your app.

Maintain a flag on your dashboard in any server call to know the last date and time of usage of your app for every respective user.If he was not used for more than 3 months for example just mark him as in-active user.